# Structure for writing / deploying a JS script made for webpages?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a script with these requirements:

1. Can be added using a `<script>` tag to a web page
2. Uses NPM packages
3. Easy to build for production
4. It will invoke a function `doSomething()` on being loaded

In the past I've only created full front end or full back end apps using javascript, never a library like this. Is there a specific standard for this? I don't need to deploy to NPM. I just need to be able to run `yarn build` or something and have it be compressed to a file that I can then deploy and link to.

Comment: Your requirements still sound like "full front end", not dual-purpose?

Comment: Yeh I guess you could say it's front end. I just don't require modifying the DOM or anything, just pure JS and invoking a function